# Changing the color in my animation

Tags: plotting, color

I'm helping my students with parametrization. I tried to change the color on the second rotation of the unit circle with this code:

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{Cos[2 t], Sin[2 t]}, {t, 0, tau}, PlotRange -> 1.2, 
  PlotStyle -> {If[t <= π, "Blue", "Red"]}],
 {{tau, 0.1}, 0, 2 π}]
```

But it remains blue after the first rotation. Can someone make a suggestion how to change the color?

Comment: "Blue" and "Red" should probably be replaced with just `Blue` and `Red`; colors are keywords in Mathematica mostly; see also `GrayLevel`, `Hue`, and `RGBColor`. Also, the parameter `t` is not defined generally outside of the first argument to the function; you should look at the `ColorFunction` option.

Comment: @user16054 Yep, my mistake. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using `ColorFunction`, as `PlotStyle` does not do variable-dependent coloring:

```
Manipulate[ParametricPlot[{Cos[2 t], Sin[2 t]}, {t, -$MachineEpsilon, τ}, 
                          ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, t}, If[t <= π, Blue, Red]], 
                          ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotRange -> 1.2],
           {{τ, 0.1}, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image: Manipulate of colored circle]

where I have also taken the liberty of offsetting the starting point in `ParametricPlot[]` to prevent errors when `τ` becomes `0`, and using the colors as symbols instead of strings.

Comment: This provided some excellent help. May I ask one more question? How can I change the thickness on the second rotation?

Comment: Now that... is an excellent question. Let me think about it.